# How to change argparse option action vs. type behavior based on argument presence?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to implement the following behavior for the CLI for my Python script:

- if the `-o` option is not present, the script does not write to a file
- if the `-o` option is present without an argument, the script writes to a default filename
- if the `-o` option is present with an argument, the script writes to a filename supplied by the user

```
$ python myscript.py               # does not write to file
$ python myscript.py -o            # writes to default.txt
$ python myscript.py -o myfile.txt # writes to myfile.txt
```

Is it possible to achieve this with `argparse`? Here's what I've tried when building my parser:

```
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', action='store_true', type=str, default=False, required=False, help="...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that this is possible, but you need to use the `const` and `nargs` options.

```
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', const='default.txt', nargs='?', type=str, default=False, required=False, help="...")
```

Read more: [`const`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#const) [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs)

Comment: Nice: I wasn't aware of `const` being used apart from `store_const` or `append_const` actions.